# constructor of class doesn't create class

Tags: java, sockets, constructor, classloader, serversocket

I am a student on holiday and I decided to make a server application for fun. So the problem is: My class - `Server.java` - is a server created with ServerSocket, but when I try to construct a Thread class - `ServerThread.java` - something I have never seen before happens. I debugged the class and when I step into the constructor of ServerThread called in `Server.java`, it doesn't go into `ServerThread` but instead goes into `ClassLoader.class`. I assume this normally also happens at some point, but now only this gets called and not the constructor of `ServerThread`.

I have been struggling with this for the past 3 days, almost non-stop, but for the love of Pete I cannot get it to work.

Here is my Server.java code:

```
    public class Server
{
private ArrayList<Socket> sockets;
private ServerSocket ss;

// Constructor and while-accept loop all in one.
public Server( int port ) throws IOException
{   
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // All we have to do is listen
    listen( port );
}

// Main routine
// Usage: java Server >port<
static public void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
{
    // Get the port # from the command line
    int port = 5003;
    // Create a Server object, which will automatically begin
    // accepting connections.
    new Server( port );
}

private void listen( int port ) throws IOException
{
    // Create the ServerSocket
    ss = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.6"));
    // Tell the world we're ready to go
    System.out.println( "Listening on " + ss );

    sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();

    // Keep accepting connections forever
    while (true)
    {
        // Grab the next incoming connection
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        // Tell the world we've got it
        System.out.println( "Connection from " + s );

        sockets.add(s);
        // Create a new thread for this connection, and then forget
        // about it
        new ServerThread( this, s );
    }
}

public void removeConnection(Socket socket) throws IOException
{
    synchronized (sockets) 
    {
        sockets.remove(socket);
        System.out.println("Closing connection at " + socket);
        socket.close();
    }
}

public void sendToAll(Socket s, String msg) throws IOException
{
    synchronized (sockets) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sockets.size(); i++)
        {
            if (!sockets.get(i).equals(s))
            {
                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sockets.get(i).getOutputStream())).write(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is my ServerThread.java code:

```
    public class ServerThread extends Thread
{
private Server server;
private Socket socket;

public ServerThread( Server server, Socket socket )
{
    // Save the parameters
    this.server = server;
    this.socket = socket;
    // Start up the thread
    start();
}

// This runs in a separate thread when start() is called in the
// constructor.
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        // Create a DataInputStream for communication; the client
        // is using a DataOutputStream to write to us
        BufferedReader din = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        // Over and over, forever ...
        while (true)
        {
            String message = "";
            try
            {
                // ... read the next message ...
                message = din.readLine();
                // ... tell the world ...
                System.out.println( "Sending "+message );

                server.sendToAll(socket, message);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("GG");
        }
    }
    catch( EOFException ie )
    {
        ie.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("GG1");
    }
    catch( IOException ie )
    {
        // This does; tell the world!
        ie.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("GG2");
    }
    finally
    {
        // The connection is closed for one reason or another,
        // so have the server dealing with it
        try {
            server.removeConnection( socket );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I hope I have made myself clear enough...

Comment: It works for me. What happens if you step *out* of the classloader code? My guess is that it was just loading your ServerThread class. Try adding logging but then run without debugging.

Comment: So you're saying `new ServerThread( this, s )`, with a breakpoint in the `ServerThread` constructor, while debugging, doesn't stop inside the `ServerThread` constructor?

Comment: Yes, when I step into ServerThread(this, s), it never goes into the constructor, it just returns and continues the loop without constructing the thread and without starting it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. It turns out the constructor was called but the program hanged at din.readLine(). I coudn't figure out why that happened because I did add a '\n' character at the end of the message, so I instead changed the BufferedReader and BufferedWriter objects to java.io.DataInputStream and java.io.DataOutputStream and used the readUTF() and writeUTF() methods, and this worked. Thank you for everyone's answers and time :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging step-by-step and you reach a `new` expression that requires a currently unloaded class, you *will* step in to the class loader.

This is normal behavior.  You will have to step out, possibly multiple times, to get back to your code.

Comment: Yes but my problem is that even though it enters the classloader, it never enters the called constructer. And there aren't any errors either.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't enter the constructor? You may have to step out 7 or 8 times to get there.

Comment: I know it because the start() method doesn't run because the run() method's contents doesn't run. The println statement doesn't execute - "Sending" doesn't appear. It's not the connection that is the problem, because it worked before, it just suddenly stopped working. The connection between the client and server is fine.

Comment: Have you inserted println statements before and after `new ServerThread(this,s);`, as well as in `ServerThread.run()` just inside the `while` loop? I suspect it's hanging at `din.readLine();`